# How i can modify to Equipment tab of the screen Daily Field Report

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm trying to modify the Equipment view, to be able to group the records.
It groups it correctly with the new code I have modify, but when I insert a new record in the Equipment tab and I still don´t save the record , then  I change the tab to Inventory and add a new record and then I change to the Equipment tab the record disappears.

I attach photos so you understand what I mean.

I need help since I have to validate so that the record in memory does not disappear when I change tabs.

I hope you can help me with issue, Thanks in advance

**No modified code**

[image]

**with modified code**

[image]

```
protected virtual IEnumerable equipment()
            {
                PXCache cache = Base.Caches[typeof(EquipmentProjection)];
                EquipmentProjection filter = (EquipmentProjection)cache.Current;
    
                foreach (PXResult<EquipmentProjection> res in SelectFrom<EquipmentProjection>
                    .Where<EquipmentProjection.dailyFieldReportId
                    .IsEqual<DailyFieldReport.dailyFieldReportId.FromCurrent>>
                    .AggregateTo<GroupBy<EquipmentProjection.timeCardCD>>.View.Select(Base))
                {
                    EquipmentProjection equipment = res;
                    yield return equipment;
                }
    
                yield return filter;
    
                cache.IsDirty = false;
            }
```

Comment: I have tried to do this, but without success. The code I have works but it seems to be missing something. So that the record in memory does not disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acumatica cannot handle a editable view that uses aggregation if I understand correctly. But for future reference you can use a PXDelegateCacheResult to make sure that the records get stored properly in the cache and do not dissapear.

```
  protected virtual IEnumerable equipment()
  {
       var result = new PXDelegateCacheResult();
       var items =  SelectFrom<EquipmentProjection>
                .Where<EquipmentProjection.dailyFieldReportId
                .IsEqual<DailyFieldReport.dailyFieldReportId.FromCurrent>>
                .AggregateTo<GroupBy<EquipmentProjection.timeCardCD>>
                .View.Select(Base)

         foreach (PXResult<EquipmentProjection> res in items)
         {
             EquipmentProjection equipment = res;
             result.Add(equipment);
         }

         return result;
   }
```